# Rearranging an Array in C to separate Negative from Positive Numbers By Maintaining the Order

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I have intended to sort the `array` by bringing negative integers in front (on the left side) from an array and leave positive integers on the right, except without changing the appearance of their order. For some reason the arrangement of negatives and positives did not work, as well as the program shows zeroes instead of positives in the `resultArr`. Would appreciate it if somebody could help with what am I doing incorrectly..

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 9

int numArr[LENGTH] = {5, -7, -87, -221, 7, 97, 1, -5, 5};
int resultArr[LENGTH];
int i;
int j = 0;
int disp;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        disp = numArr[i];
        if (disp > 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    
    j = i - 1;
    
    while (resultArr[j] > 0 && j>= 0)
    {
        resultArr[j + 1] = resultArr[j];
        j--;
    }
    resultArr[j + 1] = disp;
}

printf("Original array : %d ", *numArr);
for (i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)
{
    printf(" %d ", numArr[i]);
}
    
printf("Rearranged array : ");
for (j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
{
    printf(" %d ", resultArr[j]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `j`. Hence `j` probably has a nonsensical value, and `resultArr[j] = numArr[i];` in the first loop copies `numArr[i]` to some random location of memory, or might even crash the program, or some other undefined behaviour.

Comment: It looks like you edited your question after my comment to fix the issue with variable `j`. Is your code working now? Do you still have questions about it?

Comment: @Stef thank you for your comment, yes I edited it but the number sequence of resultArray still is the same as the numArray, as well as all the positive numbers return as zeros...

Comment: You removed the line `resultArr[j] = numArr[i];`. Did you intend to remove it? Now the first loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Stef i removed it and placed it back, the result is the same anyway. the output in both cases still look like this:
Original array : 5  -7  -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 
Rearranged array :  -7  -87  -221  0  0  0  -5  0

Comment: The line `resultArr[j + 1] = disp;` at the end is extremely suspicious; `disp` was assigned in the first loop, and is equal to `numArr[LENGTH-1]`.

Comment: @Stef without this line all I am getting in resultArr are zeroes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard for me to comment on your code, because I don't know what each loop was intended to do.

**Here is my version of the code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */

#define LENGTH 9

void moveNegativeToFront(int const *numArr, int *resultArr, int length)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++)      /* first loop: move negative to front */
  {
    if (numArr[i] < 0)
    {
      resultArr[j] = numArr[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  /* note that j is not reinitialised here */
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++)      /* second loop: move positive to back */
  {
    if (numArr[i] >= 0)
    {
      resultArr[j] = numArr[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int numArr[LENGTH] = {5, -7, -87, -221, 7, 97, 1, -5, 5};
  int resultArr[LENGTH];

  int i;

  printf("Original array : ");
  for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
  {
    printf(" %d ", numArr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  moveNegativeToFront(numArr, resultArr, LENGTH);

  printf("Rearranged array : ");
  for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
  {
    printf(" %d ", resultArr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original array :  5  -7  -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 
Rearranged array :  -7  -87  -221  -5  5  7  97  1  5
```

**Explanation of the two loops and visualization of `i` and `j` during execution:**

```
at beginning:
numArr = [ 5   -7   -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 ]
          ^ i
resArr = [                                     ]
          ^ j

during first loop:
numArr = [ 5   -7   -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 ]
                               ^ i
resArr = [-7  -87  -221                        ]
                         ^ j

just after first loop:
numArr = [ 5   -7   -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 ]
                                                 ^ i
resArr = [-7  -87  -221  -5                    ]
                             ^ j

just before second loop:
numArr = [ 5   -7   -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 ]
           ^ i
resArr = [-7  -87  -221  -5                    ]
                             ^ j

during second loop:
numArr = [ 5   -7   -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 ]
                                  ^ i
resArr = [-7  -87  -221    -5  5   7           ]
                                      ^ j

at the end:
numArr = [ 5   -7   -87  -221  7  97  1  -5  5 ]
                                                 ^ i
resArr = [-7  -87  -221    -5  5   7  97  1  5 ]
                                                 ^ j
```

**What I changed:**

- I fixed the two loops in the main algorithm, so that one clearly copies the negative numbers, and one clearly copies the positive numbers
- I added a few comments in the code to explain what it does
- I moved the main algorithm to a separate function, and the test in `main()`
- I removed all your global variables and replaced them with local variables
- I added `printf("\n");` in two places to add new lines and flush stdout.